# How to rewrite a url with a question mark?

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite, query-string

Is it possible to rewrite an url with a question a mark in it?

For instance,

```
http://localhost/mysite/search?tag=mars
```

to become this,

```
index.php?url=search&tag[key_name]=mars
```

I tried with this, but no good at all,

```
RewriteRule ^search?tag=([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$  index.php?url=search&tag[key_name]=$1&type=tag [L,QSA]
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

For `%1`,

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)tag=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^search$ index.php?url=search&tag\%5Bkey_name\%5D=%1&type=tag [L]
```

Result,

```
print_r($_GET);

Array
(
    [url] => search
    [tag] => Array
        (
            [key_name] => 
        )

    [type] => tag
)
```

For `%0`,

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)tag=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^search$ index.php?url=search&tag\%5Bkey_name\%5D=%0&type=tag [L]
```

Result,

```
print_r($_GET);

Array
(
    [url] => search
    [tag] => Array
        (
            [key_name] => tag=mars
        )

    [type] => tag
)
```

Comment: The `%{QUERY_STRING}` is handled separately from the path. Use a `RewriteCond`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing a querystring parameter value using mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497184/replacing-a-querystring-parameter-value-using-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query strings cannot be matched inside `RewriteRule`. You must use `RwwriteCond` instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)tag=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^search$ index.php?url=search&tag\%5Bkey_name\%5D=%1&type=tag [L]
```

Here:

- `[` and `]` are urlencoded as `%5b` and `%5D`
- `\%` is used to escape the literal `%` characters
- `%0` ... `%9` are the strings that were matched/captured in `RewriteCond` clause. This is just the way you use `$0` ... `$9` for `RewriteRule`
- `QSA` flag is not required
- `(^|&)` matches beginning of input (e.g. in `tag=mars&foo=bar`) or `&` (e.g. in `foo=bar&tag=mars`)
- `?:` makes mod_rewrite *not capture* this group (other this match would go in `%1`, next one in `%2`, etc)

Your PHP script will get:

```
$_GET["url"]  : search
$_GET["tag"]  : Array([key_name] => mars)
$_GET["type"] : tag
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I just tried but the `mars` is not passed into `key_name`. what does `%1` mean?

Comment: thanks for the update. I still get nothing in `key_name`... I don't get it!

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($_GET)` and post results?

Comment: Thanks. I have put the results in my edit above. with `%0`, I get an interesting result.

Comment: I think it is to do with `(?:^|&)tag=([^&]+)`. Can I ask - what `(?:^|&)` and `([^&]+)` mean?

Comment: I looked at your output, it is not possible for `$0` to contain `tag=mars` while `$1` is `""`. Something is fishy. Try removing `?:` (%1 becomes %2 in that case) and double check round brackets.

Comment: yes it is now working with `(?:^|&)tag=([^&]+)` - `?:` is the key! thank you so much!! :-)